# Running Flink 1.5 on Yarn

Tags: apache-flink

We are running Flink 1.5.0 Yarn session on a hadoop 2.6 cluster.
./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 4 -jm 1024 -tm 4096 -qu 
This however does not start any taskmanagers. The logs say Flink JobManager started with leader id 000000...
In the JobManager web interface also there are no task managers. When we submit a flink job to this jobManager, some taskmannagers do get spawned on the web interface which execute the job. Is this the expected behavior from Flink1.5.0 onwards?
Running Flink1.4.2 in same manner did spawn the taskmanagers from startup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reworking of the Flink runtime known as [FLIP-6](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65147077) was included in Flink 1.5, and it has the effect you've noticed. For a succinct description of how Flink now interacts with YARN, see [this section of the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html#background--internals).

Flink 1.5 includes a configuration option for using the previous job deployment model, known as [legacy mode](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/release-notes/flink-1.5.html#update-configuration-for-reworked-job-deployment).

Comment: "After that, the AM starts allocating the containers for Flink’s TaskManagers, which will download the jar file and the modified configuration from the HDFS. Once these steps are completed, Flink is set up and ready to accept Jobs." This is what is there in the internals documentation. Clearly not helpful/explaining what is happening.. How does Flink decides the resources for a job just by degree of parallelism?